# ApiPlatform - how to add "CASE WHEN product.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END" in OrderFilter?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

Is there any way to create custom `OrderFilter` and add to `querybuilder->orderBy()` "`CASE WHEN`"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add it in the addSelect() just like :

```
->addSelect('case when product.name IS NULL then 1 else 0 end AS HIDDEN name_is_null')
            ->addOrderBy('name_is_null', 'ASC')
```

`...as HIDDEN...` Is used to tell doctrine to not add the following `name_is_full` column in the data result.